# How can I write out the Real-TIme Recurrent Learning Gradient equations for a network?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, learning-algorithms

This question is about Real-Time Recurrent Learning Gradient on a Recurrent neural network .

How can I write out the RTRL equations for a network ?

Before present an example give let's introduce some notation :

**Notation** 
[image: Notation]

So the network for which we want to write the RTRL equations is the following :

**Network**
[image: Network]

A similar question can be found [here](https://hagan.okstate.edu/NNDesign.pdf) at page 561 for another network .